# Configuring freshly installed Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Coming from a windows history, I'd just managed to get my first Ubuntu computer running with Apache, PHP5, Mysql, Memcached and some other goodies to work as a local development workstation.

But, to learn the basics, since i know less than nothing about Apaches configurations and recommended settings:

What's common sense and good practice to start on when configuring a fresh install of Apache on a Ubuntu box?
I am assuming that something needs to be done out-of-the box to make it use its full potential together with the rest of my packages?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Need to know a little more about what you want to *do* with Apache.  Barring that, good practice is to turn it off :-)

Comment: What to do? I want to use it to take care of my PHP files in my local environement, so it's not like I'm setting up a new web hosting service :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apache works fine out of the box if all you are doing is serving some PHP files locally. Most of the tuning required is to cater for scaling up to larger volumes of traffic.

Just install the apache, memcached and the php modules you need with apt-get and you'll find it Just Works.

Answer (score 1):

@Industrial I think you should read Orielly Apache cook book it has a lot of good examples for configuring Apache.http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001919 I have myself read it though I knew apache but for my own understanding.